# How to update column only is its empty in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using below query to update the column. Now what I want that I want to update these columns only when it is empty or null. How can I achieve this ?

```
 db.execSQL("UPDATE FieldTestDataTemp SET 
           Image1 = '" + f10.image1 + "', 
           Image2 = '" + f10.image2 + "', 
           Image3 = '" + f10.image3 + "', 
           Image4 = '" + f10.image4 + "', 
           Image5 = '" + f10.image5 + "',
           starRating = '" + starRating1 + "' ");
```

Comment: you have to know first what fields has a null value

Comment: I have updated my query. I want to check this for every column in above query.

Comment: I don't think you can implement your logic in a single `UPDATE` statement.  A single statement will either update all columns, or none of them.

Comment: What is the type of the image columns?

Comment: It cant be done with only one update only in a row

Comment: @reds Not true, but he would have to always update a column, even if the value does not change.

Comment: but he need to update only the fields that contains null values

Comment: In image colums I am updating base64 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mysql we used to use this query

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = 'Your value'
WHERE field 
IS NULL
OR LENGTH(field)=0
```

You have to set multiple query to set multiple column condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters like this  to a common method that will return you the number of records updated

```
public int updateRecords(String table, ContentValues values,
                             String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        int a = db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
        return a;
    }
```

and in this db is SQLiteDatabase object

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to OP comment

> I want to check this for every column in above query.

If I understand you correctly you want to update each column only if this column is empty. For this you need to run separate query for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite has [coalesce](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) function that takes variable number of parameters and returns first not null.

```
UPDATE field UPDATE FieldTestDataTemp SET Image1 = coalesce(Image1, f10.image1)...
```

However - this not covers situation with empty fields so you need to carry about them (ex. set to null).

It's also good idea to use `prepareStatement()` / `exec()` instead of `execSQL()`. It allows to use placeholders instead of  string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do a single `UPDATE` and also check for null/empty:

```
UPDATE FieldTestDataTemp
SET Image1 = CASE WHEN Image1 IS NULL OR Image1 = ''
                  THEN f10.image1
                  ELSE Image1
             END,
    Image2 = CASE WHEN Image1 IS NULL OR Image2 = ''
                  THEN f10.image2
                  ELSE Image2,
    ...
```

But this will update *every* column in the `UPDATE` statement, even if the base 64 image string already be not null and not empty.

A possibly cleaner way to handle this would be to update each column separately.  In this case, we can just add a `WHERE` clause to only update for empty/null image strings:

```
UPDATE FieldTestDataTemp
SET Image1 = f10.image1
WHERE COALESCE(Image1, '') <> ''
```